# How do you sample from a list of probabilities in python

Tags: python, statistics

How do you sample from a list of probabilities that add up to 1 in python.

Ex. 
List: [0.1, 0.8, 0.1]
The first element would be chosen 10% of the time, the second 80%, and the third 10%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the weights allowed by the random.choices function. For example:

```
import random

floats = [0.1, 0.8, 0.1]
weights = [0.1, 0.8, 0.1]
k = 1

choice = random.choices(population=floats, weights=weights, k=k)
print(choice)
```

It returns it as a list because you can have `k` equal the number of items you want to choose.

Comment: That's a clever solution. Unfortunately I am using floats, so I don't think creating a list of the required size would be practical

Comment: `random.choice actually`
 accepts a vector of probabilities associated to the input vector

Comment: I edited my answer given the above feedback.